# Why does "not" care about "List.exists" input in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I made a function that identifies if a certain object has repetition as following: (PS: test is passing)

```
(* ListOfPattern -> Pattern -> String List -> List.exists (function) ->  bool*)
val check_pat =
  let 
    fun patternToVars p =
      case p of
        Variable x => [x]
      | TupleP lop => List.foldl (fn (p, acc) => (patternToVars p) @ acc) [] lop
      | _ => []
        
    fun isDuplicated lov =
      case lov of
        [] => false
      | lov::lov' => List.exists (fn prevString => prevString = lov) lov' orelse isDuplicated lov'
  in
    not o isDuplicated o patternToVars 
    (* Cannot understand why `not o` works but `not` does not, duplicate returns bool in all 
        cases and there is no need for piping *)
  end
```

But if I remove `o` from `not o isDuplicated o patternToVars` and make it `not isDuplicated o patternToVars` it returns the following error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: bool
  operand:         ''Z list -> bool
  in expression:
    not isDuplicated
```

And the question is "why `isDuplicated` returning a list?"

Comment: This is usually called "composition" and not "piping". `o` is the function composition operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message does not say that `isDuplicated` returns a list, it says that `isDuplicated` is a function with the type `''Z list -> bool`, and that you're trying to apply `not` to it when `not` requires a `bool` argument.

`not o` is not a meaningful "unit"; `o` is a binary operator, and `f o g` is equivalent to `fn x => f (g x)`.

Because function application has higher precedence than `o`,

```
not isDuplicated o patternToVars
```

is equivalent to

```
(not isDuplicated) o patternToVars
```

That is, you're trying to negate the function `isDuplicated`, not its result.

Perhaps your particular issue becomes more obvious if you add the argument and nest explicit function applications; the first is equivalent to

```
fn p => not (isDuplicated (patternVars p))
```

while the second is equivalent to

```
fn p => (not isDuplicated) (patternVars p)
```

which you can see is very different.

---

Another attempt to clarify:

Perhaps it becomes clearer if we define composition as a function instead of as an infix operator:

```
fun compose (f, g) = fn x => f (g x)
```

or even

```
fun compose (f, g) = f o g
```

Then,

```
not o isDuplicated o patternToVars
```

is the same as

```
compose (not, compose (isDuplicated, patternToVars))
```

while

```
not isDuplicated o patternToVars
```

is the same as

```
compose (not isDuplicated, patternToVars)
```

Comment: Execuse me but, i still did not understand, maybe because i am biased to java, if the function has `bool` return type, then what difference does it make if it is a function that takes `Z list` or not? shouldn't all we care about is the return type?

Comment: I still did not understand This `fn p => (not isDuplicated) (patternVars p)`. To be specific, how does the brackets around `not isDuplicated` different from `not isDuplicated o patternToVars`. Do you mean that `not` is applied to `PatternVars`? (thus we need braces).

Comment: No, `not` is applied to `isDuplicated`, and `fn p => (not isDuplicated) (patternVars p)` is *the same* as `not isDuplicated o patternToVars` . If this were Java, it would be the difference between `!isDuplicated(patternVars(p))` and `(!isDuplicated)(patternVars(p))`, which would be equally wrong.